# Sorting values in couchdb

Tags: sorting, couchdb

I'm trying to pull scores back from this view

```
"scores": {
    "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.appName, {_id:doc.username, username:doc.username, credits:doc.credits, avatar:doc.avatar}) }"
},
```

I pass in the appname and it returns the scores. The issue is the scores wont sort correctly. When I try to sort them they only sort by the first number so something like so

```
1500
50
7
900
```

As you can see the first numbers are sorted ASC but the whole number itself isn't. Is it possible to have couchdb sort the scores if the appname is the key?

Answer (score 1):

is `doc.appName` a string?  Turn it into a number:

```
function(doc) { 
    emit(parseInt(doc.appName), {_id:doc.username, username:doc.username, credits:doc.credits, avatar:doc.avatar});
    //   ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is a string it's used to identify what app the user is trying to fetch the scores from

Comment: couchdb sorts strings in a manner that works consistently for all strings, that is, in lexicographic (ie, dictionary) order.  it does sort numbers numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a complex key:

```
emit([doc.appName, doc.score], null)
```

Then query using a range:

```
startkey=["app1", 0]&endkey=["app1", {}]
```